# .map is not a function when using useDispatch or useState in onClick

Tags: reactjs, redux, onclick, react-hooks, use-state

I have a mapped out series of data coming from redux which is displays components as stages 1 and 2. (in the future I plan to have much more) What I want is to dispatch a action depending on the id of the component. Here is how I made it:

```
const stageList = stages.map ((stage)=> 
    <Stage key={stage.id} onClick={()=>dispatch(selectStage(stage.id))}
        stagename={stage.name} exp={stage.exp} id={stage.id}/>
)
```

and the actual component is built like this

```
const Stage = ({onClick, stagename, exp, id}) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={onClick} className={styles.item}>
            <img style={{height:"15em"}} alt="Map of the Stage" src={map}></img>
            <div className={styles.inner}>
                <h4>Stage {id}: {stagename}</h4>
                <p>LVL {exp}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But whenever I try that i get:

> stages.map is not a function

And its not the redux state either, because console.log(state.id) works fine and outputs the correct stage id.
Something I tried, was using useState with useEffect to get the stage.id value with useState and dispatch the state when it updates.

```
const [stageSelected, setStageSelected] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(selectStage(stageSelected));
    console.log(stageSelected);
}, [stageSelected])

const info = useSelector(state => state.info);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const stages = info.stages

const stageList = stages.map ((stage)=> 
    <Stage key={stage.id} onClick={()=> setStageSelected(stage.id)}
        stagename={stage.name} exp={stage.exp} id={stage.id}/>
)
```

But to no avail either.

The value of stages is

```
stages: [
    {
        name: "Health and Safety",
        tagname:"healthAndSafety",
        id:0,
        exp:3,
        steps: [
            {
                name: "Correct Uniform",
                tagname:"correctUniform",
            },
            {
                name: "Coffee Machine",
                tagname:"coffeeMachine",
            },
            {
                name: "Food Safety",
                tagname:"foodSafety",
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Customer Service",
        tagname:"customerService",
        id:1,
        exp:5,
        steps: [
            {
                name: "Correct Uniform",
                tagname:"correctUniform",
            },
            {
                name: "Coffee Machine",
                tagname:"coffeeMachine",
            },
            {
                name: "Food Safety",
                tagname:"foodSafety",
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to find a similar answer to this ( with setState and componentDidChange), but unfortunately I couldn't find the same combination of things in the problem

Comment: What is the value of `stages`?

Comment: Ahh, sure. I just posted the value of stages

Comment: My assumption is that, sometimes you will be getting array (mentioned above). You have to find the value when it is failing.

Comment: Aha! I checked the value of stage when it failed and It was actually a problem with the redux reducer changing the state incorrectly. Thank you! I shouldve posted the action creator and reducer but I wasnt thinking it was relevant sorry

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a problem with the reducer which was incorrectly changing state. Shouldve posted the reducer sorry. anyways thank you @UKS